# Do I get more candies if I sent back evolved Pokemon to the professor?

Tags: pokemon-go

Currently, any duplicate Pokemon with a low combat score I find, I'll send back to the professor for candies to evolve my high ranking ones.

Yet I wonder if I should evolve some of them first with candies and sent them back then. Is there a bonus of sending back evolved pokemon in regards of candy? Or would it be a waste of resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bonus for sending back evolved pokemon as of now so you should just send them back. However I would still send them back if the have low CP or if you simply don't need them anymore.

However the only exception is if you save a ton of weak pokemon and obtain a lot of candies so you can do a lot of evolutions while you have a lucky egg on which will grant you a lot of trainer experience since all evolutions give you at least 500 experience. You get more if the evolved pokemon isn't one you have in your pokedex yet.

Source: Personal experience